# Is there any method to integration of DialogFlow with Google Assistant? I didn't see any option of Integration in DialogFlow in left pane

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to implement DialogFlow. I am through from all the steps except Integration with Google Assistant. Is there any method to integration of DialogFlow with Google Assistant? I didn't see any option of Integration in DialogFlow in left pane but in tutorial it's given. Please tell me either I am missing something or it's removed from the left pane? Thank you!

Comment: I am working in EU2 region

Answer (score 1):

In EU2 , Integrations isn't available.
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/how/region

Comment: Thank you @Elkios for your prompt reply. I will check accordingly.